# Can there be a segment of regular cardinals with the tree property capped by an almost-strongly-compact?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Recall that a cardinal $\kappa$ is $(\lambda,\infty)$-almost-strongly-compact if every $\kappa$-complete filter can be refined to a $\lambda$-complete ultrafilter. A cardinal $\mu$ has the *tree property* if every $\mu$-sized tree with $\mu$-small levels has a branch of length $\mu$. (If in addition $\mu$ is inaccessible then $\mu$ is weakly compact.)

**Question:** Can the following constellation occur?

- $\mu$ -- weakly inaccessible with the tree property
- $\kappa$ -- a $(\mu^+,\infty)$-strongly-compact cardinal
- every regular $\nu \in [\mu, \kappa)$ -- has the tree property.

I suspect this would be too good to be true. But I don't know much --  <strike>for all I know, maybe almost strong compactness implies inaccessibility, in which case of course the answer is *no*. But I'm having trouble tracking down even that information.</strike>

If $\kappa$ can be taken to be $(\mu,\infty)$-strongly-compact, that might be good enough for what I need. Also it should suffice for only the successor cardinals in $(\mu,\kappa)$ to have the tree property.

I apologize for the repeated changes to the question.

Comment: What fails when $\mu$ is strongly compact?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks, I realized that I was not asking what I intended to ask. I think you're right that clearly if $\mu$ is strongly compact then it has the tree property and $\mu^+$ is almost strongly compact. It turns out I had asked the wrong question!

Comment: Do you know if a double successor cardinal can be almost strongly compact at all? I think that it would mean that there is a non-principle ultrafilter with completeness which is not a measurable cardinal, which is impossible.

Comment: @YairHayut  I wouldn't be surprised if I am missing something very, very basic. At the risk of being a bit ridiculous, I might change my question again.

Comment: I think that this is still impossible (assuming $\mu^+ < \kappa$). Since $\kappa$ is $(\mu,\infty)$-strongly compact, there is a measurable cardinal $\mu \leq \zeta \leq \kappa$. In particular, there is a strongly inaccessible cardinal, $\rho$, in the half-open interval $[\mu, \kappa)$. In particular, $\rho^{<\rho} = \rho$ and the tree property will fail at $\rho^+$.

Comment: @YairHayut Thanks, I was not aware that the tree property definitely fails at the successor of any strongly inaccessible $\rho$ -- I thought this was something very peculiar to $\omega_1$.  I would happily accept this as an answer. Is it easy to generalize standard constructions of an Aronszajn tree on $\omega_1$ to $\rho^+$?

Comment: @YairHayut Actually -- where does $\rho < \kappa$ come from?

Comment: Tim, it's a theorem of Specker, if my memory serves me right, that under the assumption that $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa$, then $\kappa^+$ does not have a tree property. I think you can find the proof in Kanamori, but I'm not sure. The construction is somehow similar to the standard Aronszajn tree, but of course slightly different.